# can any one guide me what is error in this code?

Tags: angularjs

Question :The following ng-option code is not working i not able to identify error

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
This is example of ng-option
</title>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ngOption = angular.module("ngOptionApp",[]);

ngOption.controller("ngOptionController",function($scope){
$scope.data =   ["Maharashtra","Panjab","Rajsathan","Gujrat","Karnatakka","Kerala"];
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "ngOptionApp" ng-controller = "ngOptionController">
<select ng-model = "xyz" ng-option = "x for x in data">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get no error in console? If you get some please paste it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-option` should be [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    This is example of ng-option
  </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var ngOption = angular.module("ngOptionApp", []);

    ngOption.controller("ngOptionController", function($scope) {
      $scope.data = ["Tamil Nadu","Maharashtra", "Panjab", "Rajsathan", "Gujrat", "Karnatakka", "Kerala"];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngOptionApp" ng-controller="ngOptionController">
  <select ng-model="xyz" ng-options="x for x in data">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to tip i am new on stackoverflow